# How to use Macro argument as string literal?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, string-literals

I am trying to figure out how to write a macro that will pass both a string literal representation of a variable name along with the variable itself into a function.

For example given the following function.

```
void do_something(string name, int val)
{
   cout << name << ": " << val << endl;
}
```

I would want to write a macro so I can do this:

```
int my_val = 5;
CALL_DO_SOMETHING(my_val);
```

Which would print out: `my_val: 5`

I tried doing the following:

```
#define CALL_DO_SOMETHING(VAR) do_something("VAR", VAR);
```

However, as you might guess, the VAR inside the quotes doesn't get replaced, but is just passed as the string literal "VAR". So I would like to know if there is a way to have the macro argument get turned into a string literal itself.

Comment: How are you trying to use this?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Use the preprocessor [`#` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators):

```
#define CALL_DO_SOMETHING(VAR) do_something(#VAR, VAR);
```

Answer (score 45):

You want to use the stringizing operator:

```
#define STRING(s) #s

int main()
{
    const char * cstr = STRING(abc); //cstr == "abc"
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps you try this solution:

```
#define QUANTIDISCHI 6
#define QUDI(x) #x
#define QUdi(x) QUDI(x)
. . . 
. . .
unsigned char TheNumber[] = "QUANTIDISCHI = " QUdi(QUANTIDISCHI) "\n";
```

Comment: How does this answer the question or how is it helpful?

Comment: @jirigracik -- It allows to get string presentation of macro expansion as well, unlike other answers

Comment: I think it would be useful to explain why having just `QUDI(x)` is not enough.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The explanation as to why it works would be useful, but it solved my problem (which the other answers did not).

Answer (score 14):

```
#define NAME(x) printf("Hello " #x);
main(){
    NAME(Ian)
}
//will print: Hello Ian
```

Comment: I’m not totally sure, but it looks like `"Hello" #x"` (and `#x "Hello"`) causes the string to be glued together without space, which is what is desired in some cases, so this is fairly good answer.

Comment: @Smar Make sure you put a space after the constant string Hello:  `"Hello " #x`

Comment: Okay I thought so, you should edit that to your answer too since it’s valuable piece of information :)

Comment: #define NAME(x) printf("Hello %s", #x);

Answer (score 0):

```
#define THE_LITERAL abcd

#define VALUE(string) #string
#define TO_LITERAL(string) VALUE(string)

std::string abcd = TO_LITERAL(THE_LITERAL); // generates abcd = "abcd"
```