# How does C++ assert access input as a string

Tags: c++, input, assert

I'm relatively new to C++, so go easy.  When assert gets something that evaluates to false, I get this in the terminal:

```
test: test.cpp:185: void test(): Assertion `actual == testing` failed.
Aborted
```

How does assert get the input as a string?  Wouldn't assert just "see" true or false?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Macro argument as string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507264/how-to-use-macro-argument-as-string-literal)

Comment: What does your assert statement look like, add the code to the question -- the answer lies in that information

Comment: I'd delete it since this question doesn't add much more to what is already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own version of assert as a macro. This may or may not be how your compiler implements it.

Since `#something` will expand to a stringified version of it, you can do:

```
#define str(s) #s
#define assert(x) if(!x) {print(".... Assertion `" str(s) "` failed.")
```

See [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) for more information.