# How to capture argument expression as string literal without using macro?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

In C, it is quite common to capture argument as string literl via macro as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10507317/4794308):

```
#define CALL_DO_SOMETHING(VAR) do_something(#VAR, VAR);
```

But on the other hand, there are many projects with policies against the usage of macro and recommend always using templates instead.

I am wondering if it is possible to express the similar syntax in a modern C++  way or it is yet another corner case where macro has to be used?

Answer (score 2):

Stringification can only be done by MACRO.